# Free API to broadcast to Twitter, Facebook, Youtube, etc

Tags: social-networking

I was wondering if anyone has come across some abstracted API that allows you to link to all these various social outlets to broadcast updates, pictures, videos etc.?

Comment: All of those networks have well documented APIs, used by hundreds of applications, complete with code samples in any conceivable programming language. Have you tried googling for anything specific?

Comment: Individually, most (all?) these site's have a well worn API.  Maybe you should put the emphasis on `abstracted` and/or  indicate your desire to do postings to multiple sites if that is what your question is about.

Comment: I'm looking to merge them all. Photo goes out to Facebook, Twitter, Youtube, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the API at ping.fm if it covers all the services/etc you wish to access. Their API becomes the abstraction. Supports REST, so should work in just about any tech you use

http://groups.google.com/group/pingfm-developers/web/api-documentation?_done=%2Fgroup%2Fpingfm-developers%3F

Comment: Awesome. I'll have to check it out!

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a common API for such a purpose that is rather new, but is gaining adoption among many of the popular social media sites:

[Open Social](http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/)
[Wikipedia: Open Social](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSocial)
[OpenSocial.org](http://www.opensocial.org/)

Hope this helps.